# Android App Add-on Structure

Tags: android, add-on, filefilter

How to incorporate add-ons to my app?

Add-ons for this example will be new levels for a game app but they could also be items, models, features, etc.

My thoughts on the structure is this:

My app has 10 levels and user downloads a new 11th level.  My app downloads this new level to a predefined directory under the root directory of my app such as...myAppRootDir/Addons/Levels/.

In order to present the user with this new level, a file (such as myAppFeatures.xml) is updated at every download with an array of levels, items, models, features, etc.  To do this, I believe I'll need to become familiar with [File](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html) class and [FileFilter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileFilter.html) interface.

Now that myAppFeatures.xml contains an array of addons, features, etc., I can then reference this file in my app to display a ListView of either addons, features, etc. depending on which list user chooses to view.

I imagine that when user selects the item from the list, I'll be passing a unique ID so that I can initiate intents, animations, boolean logic, etc.  Maybe this is handled better with [Android SQL Databases](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

Does this structure make sense?